# Trigger typeahead (bootstrap) by @ only

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Twitter Bootstrap. Trigger typehead by @ only. I am working on a twitter web app. currently typehead triggers by any matching letter. However I want it to be triggered by if user types @ and then matching letter.

Comment: does typeahead not triggers search by `@`?

Comment: it does, but i want it to be limited to @ trigger only.. it also trigger with any character too

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite Bootstrap's typeahead JS file yourself to limit it to trigger search on `@` only.

This is the only way.